# How can i active my current link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make my current page active when user click on the nav bar .
I tried alot but fail to do so,
Please Correct me, ignore grammar mistake
I want if user click on about  us , about us should be active and vice versa.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">CMS</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item " id="home">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="admin">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: the current page is active - and when you click on one of those links, that page gets loaded, and is the current page and is active

Comment: Just set an extra class on the a href for the active page

Comment: you can add the `:active` selector in CSS to do something with your active `anchor`, i.e. `a:active{ //do something; }`

Comment: `active` only works for the click it doesn't stay active. For that you'd have to use `:focus`

Comment: how can i make changes so that when user click on any navigation menu , it will make to that particular part

Comment: this depends on how you have built the site. Are you manually creating each html page or are you using a template style where the nav/header/footer are dynamically loaded in like on a wordpress site? Because both types have 2 very very different solutions.

Comment: manually creating each html page

Comment: Then you will either have to put a class like `active` or `current` on the respective appropriate link in each single page; or do this via JavaScript on the client-side (loop through the navigation links and check which of them has a href that matches the current URL path.)

Comment: https://github.com/shankarsingh482/asdf/blob/a9d79c215b719599a9b602d3cd61edb1f471878c/hello/asdf.txt

Comment: please  check this

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax.

```html
.navbar-nav .nav-item a:active {
    color: #color-code;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item a:focus {
    color: #color-code;
}
```

Comment: @shankarsingh, check jsfiddle below.
https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/LrMsA/1428/